# One-dimensional Harmonic oscillator potential problem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, harmonic-oscillator

I'm thinking about a problem that goes like this:

> Let a charged particle is in the ground state of a one dimensional harmonic oscillator potential (generated by electrical means). Now let us suppose that I suddenly switched off the power so that the potential disappears. What will happen to particle?

I'm thinking that when I switch off the power the particle must behave like free particle, so it should oscillate about the same mean point, and the amplitude will increase as time will pass. But if you think classically it seems that the particle must shoot out of the well and move out towards infinity in one of two possible directions. Or both of my ideas may be wrong. Please Help.

Comment: Just express the ground state of the harmonic oscillator as a "superposition" of free particle states. Then it should be easy to see with what probability you will measure something to occur.

Comment: You *know* about the spreading of a free Gaussian wavepacket, no? See Wikipedia.

Comment: Yes I do know about that.

Comment: I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. In the future, please add this tag to this type of problem. This is one of the things that we ask you to do in our homework policy: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange

Comment: Please reference the source of this homework question. This is one of the things that we ask you to do in our homework policy: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange

Comment: This is not an home work problem.

Answer (score 1):

If the particle is at an eigenstate of the harmonic oscillator, then its wavefunction is characterized by zero expectation value of the position $\langle n | x | n \rangle = 0$. For the ground state the wavefunction is a Gaussian. Then removing the harmonic potential will lead, as you said, to the particle keep having a zero expectation value of the position (and momentum, by the way), with the width of the wave function increasing with time.

The contradiction with the classical picture is because the eigenstates of the harmonic oscillator are not a good approximation for the classical state, even at $n\gg 1$. The classical picture is achieved when one considers the [coherent state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_states). This is a superposition of eigenstates which has $\langle \alpha | x | \alpha \rangle \neq 0$ in general, and indeed the expectation value oscillates in time just like in the classical case. Starting with this state and removing the harmonic potential at some time will lead to the particle moving to $x \to \pm \infty$ depending on its expectation value of momenta at the time when the harmonic potential was turned off.

Answer (score 1):

In the description provided by QM,  a particle in a harmonic potential **does not oscillate** around any point. There is no trajectory, no amplitude and no oscillation at all. The only thing you can say is that there is a gaussian-like probability density with its maximum at the minimum of the parabolic potential.

If at some time  the harmonic potential would disappear, the gaussian wave packet will be the initial condition for a time dependent solution of the Schrödinger equation. It turns out that this time evolution will correspond to an increase of the width of the gaussian. This implies that, at variance with the classical problem,  there will be always a fifty-fifty  probability of finding the particle moving towards one direction or the other and this probability is  independent on the exact time the potential is dropped.